# Jquery How to stop a refresh when click a navigation

Tags: jquery, html, refresh

Sorry for my bad english...
I have a problem in jquery when i cklick a buttom is refresch a navigation...
Somebody help me please :)

demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/4H942/2/

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a click event on an anchor tag, you need to use `preventDefault`.  For example:

```
$('.3').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".middle").offset().top
    }, 2000);                   
});
```

More info on how `preventDefault` works: [jQuery - event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to know without knowing exactly where the issue is, but you could need e.preventDefault() or e.stopPropagation() e.g.

```
$('.button').on('click',function(e) {
     //do something
     e.preventDefault();     // stops default button action, e.g. submitting a form
     e.stopPropagation();    // stops event bubbling back to parent element
   }  
   return false;         /// stops default link action
});
```

where .button is the class of the element thats triggering the event.
Note these are examples of issues you may be having, but without knowing the problem you are experiencing I can't say which - if any - will work.

Comment: Note that `.live` is deprecated in JQuery 1.7. You should use `.on` for JQuery 1.7+. Also OP doesn't have any class called `button` to select with `.button` apparently. I see it's probably just an example, but using the `$('button')` tag selector might be more demonstrative.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté The OP didnt specify what problem he was having with what sort of element, and the jsfiddle didn't help so as I said it is an example of solutions that may fix the problem depending on what it is... True about live, (its code from a project I worked on a whiel ago) but as he wasn't using it I assumed he's only take the relevant code that solved the problem

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding a note for whoever may try your code on JQuery 1.7+ may find themselves with a deprecated function. :P

Comment: @FabrícioMatté fair point... as I said its an old code example but I'll change it in case anyone else may take it as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding `return false;`  to the click function in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is happens often when you a form and you click on the submit button, to prevent the browser from refreshing the page just do this in the HTML :

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
...
</form>
```

If you have a link of a button that refreshes the page, do this :

```
$('.myLinkOrButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```